# Valid input to avoid error (using re:match)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to retrieve output that would avoid generating an error message "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'". I believe the error is due to output of "matchObj" being 'None'.   Bottom is my code.

```
def processCcDtMdyStamp(datestamp):
    matchObj = re.match(r'^(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)\s', datestamp)
    (month, day, year) = (matchObj.group(1), matchObj.group(2), matchObj.group(3))
    return "%s/%s/%s" % (month, day, year)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(processCcDtMdyStamp(' 1/6/2015 '))
```

What would be a valid input (datestamp) rather than ' 1/6/2015'?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Trim the whitespaces around the `1/6/2015` and see if it works. But, why using regular expressions instead of trying to load the string into datetime via `datetime.strptime()`?

Comment: Or remove `^` from the RE.

Comment: Or add a `\s*` after the `^` (and if you want add a `*$` as well at the end, so you trim within the regex).

Answer (score 0):

- [`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) will start to match at the beginning of the string, so the `^` is redundant. Also, consider using [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) instead as then the pattern is not confined to the beginning of the string and you can just match the digits and slashes.
- Because your input has a space at the beginning and your pattern doesn't, it finds no matches. Consider using `\s?` at the beginning and end of your pattern if a space is likely, or trim whitespaces before you apply regex.

---

```
>>> import re
>>> datestamp = ' 1/6/2015 '
>>> matchObj = re.search(r'(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)', datestamp)
>>> matchObj.group(1)
'1'
```